# Show javascript visualization in java?

Tags: java, javascript, visualization

I want to use javascript libraries to make visualizations like D3 and many other cool ones. But my main application that generates the data is written in java. Is there a way to write a javascript in a java component and then display the visualization from java? Of course I need to pass the data from java to javascript in order to make the visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.6 you can include JavaScript in Java using the ScriptEngine class. You can call functions from java, pass arguments and read results.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Short example of loading a javascript and calling a function:

```
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("somejavascriptinthesamepackage.js"));

        engine.eval(reader);
        reader.close();

        String result = (String) engine.eval("someFunction(" + <insert argement> + "));");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give more data about how the user is viewing the data, is it a web application, is the user viewing the data from a web browser and so on...

However, you can generate your data in java and then pass a JSON string to the js code. And the js code will take care of the display.

A good JSON  lib is: Jackson.